# TailwindCSS neutral-500 color no longer working after installing daisyUI

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

I have been using tailwindcss for my react project and would now like to use daisy-ui in addition. I installed it as instructed and added the plugin to my `tailwind.config`. After doing this some of the designs in the page look off. In particular the ones styled with `border-neutral-500`, `bg-neutral-500` - for these colors I also no longer see the little color indicator in vscode.

I am not using a custom theme but when looking at it it seems daisyUI is specifying its own version of the `neutral` color. https://daisyui.com/theme-generator/ vs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors - is this the source of the problem? How can I avoid this?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there is really conflict with utilities. DaisyUI [extending](https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/blob/master/src/index.js#L120) theme colors with its own

You may reassign `neutral` color palette again with default Tailwind values like

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                neutral: colors.neutral,
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        require("daisyui")
    ],
}
```

This way both Tailwind `bg-neutral-500` and Daisy `btn-neutral` (for example) will work

Comment: This worked!! But I am surprised that this was necessary since daisyui is supposed to integrate well with tailwind. I also found no official documentation or anyone else asking this question - any idea why?

Comment: Found [this issue](https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/issues/683)

Comment: According to that issue, the above approach will only reenable the tailwind colors - instead they suggest to rename the tailwind color with `neutralgray: colors.neutral`